# The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid at Xcode

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I tried to run the program on my device and I got that error `The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid`. I have tried all discussions provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088441/the-identity-used-to-sign-the-executable-is-no-longer-valid). All didn't work for me. I deleted all developer certificates and get new certificate from Apple and put it into the keychain. Then I made new development provisioning profile as `Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID` (to be generic). The status is active at Apple's developer site. So I put it into provisioning profile. I choose the correct certificate and profile at Code Signing from Build Phases at Xcode. I did all what I can think of, but that error never disappear. My Xcode version is 6.4 and my iOS is 8.4, all latest versions. What could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Is your team selected? General -> Identity -> Team

Comment: Where to select? Yes team is selected.

Comment: General -> Identity -> Team is selected. But can't find Targets. Where is it?

Comment: You must have selected the Your app's target to see "General -> Identity -> Team "

Comment: Yes this is the one with my Apple ID right. That is correct. i have added correct Account using my Apple ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84649/discussion-between-batuman-and-munahil).

Comment: I found out that my certificate is not valid yet. What does it mean? I checked in the KeyChain Access

Comment: May be it has expired

Comment: Are you creating the certificate following all steps?

Answer (score 0):

Check device UDID is correctly added and also check if device is added in provision profile or not

Comment: i started from scratch. Certificates is newly created. Identifier is new and make it using my app bundle id. Device also made sure my UDID (just different in Capital and small letter, i think no matter). Provision profile is produced by Xcode, so now new profile has my app bundle name, so i am sure that is my new profile. Even like that i still have this error The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid at Xcode.

Comment: I found out that my certificate is not valid yet. What does it mean? I checked in the KeyChain Access

Comment: Have you checked code signing identify. Setting other invalid identity may also give you problem.

Comment: i make sure that i have only one provision profile and set it. so I have sure they are valid

Comment: Check in both Project and Target of Xcode properties.

Comment: If you are using Icloud, check icloud in capabilities of targets

Answer (score 0):

All what they post above are correct. The problem sometimes depends on some small issues individually. For me how I solved is
(1)I started from scratch. All certificates, app id , provisioning profile etc everything I made new in the portal. In the step making provisioning profile, profile should link to certificate and your device.
(2)Then need to check the development certificate is valid. Sometimes, the certificate is not valid immediately. For that, I reset the system clock and timezone at both device and Mac pc. I am not sure because of resetting the clocks at both devices or not, when I reboot the systems the certificate became valid. Then it works afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the portal, deleted all of my certs (no live apps currently) and used the 'create' btn from the accounts menu:

Preferrences | View Details | Action => 'Reset'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove your apple id from Xcode preference and add it back again. Clean, rebuild and make sure coding signing is correct in project settings. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem. Just from "https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production/create" re-created the new Provisioning Profiles. Then download and install the new Provisioning Profiles of (Development and Distribution).

[image]