# Got error "The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid."when debug on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

I am using Xcode 7 beta 6 on Yosemite, but I have encounter the problem

> The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.

Error when I am trying to build my app on my iPhone. The detailed information is:

> Please verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your
>   signing certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018).

So I can't debug in my iPhone device now.

Anyone has any idea for this?

Comment: Ahem... Did you check that the clock on your device is set properly, and that your signing certificate isn't expired?

Comment: Everything is good, I've checked everything

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088441/the-identity-used-to-sign-the-executable-is-no-longer-valid

Comment: I've already tried what they said, but nothing worked

Comment: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-the-identity-used-to-sign-the-executable-is-no-longer-valid-error-in-xcode/

Comment: I had same issue not long ago. Try to restart everything, clear derived data and module cache, delete app from device, reconnect device.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I'm having the same problem and nothing has worked so farm ...

Answer (score 2):

This is due to changes in the provisioning file not present on your machine.

Quick fix (`Xcode 7 iOS9`):

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> Select Apple ID -> View Details -> Download All
```

now try to run the code.

Note: if still the problem persists, follow step mentioned above for every Apple ID and try to run again.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new certificate and regenerate the provisioning profile - and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem. Just from "https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production/create" re-created the new Provisioning Profiles. Then download and install the new Provisioning Profiles of (Development and Distribution). 
[image]