# The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid (iOS 8+ / Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

> The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
>
> Please verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your signing certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018).

I've already tried almost everything I've found on SO but nothing worked for me.

[image]

I'm not sure when it started to happen, I think it was just after I tried to add a share extension to my app.

I've re-generated the provisioning profiles after adding the share extension (and enabling the app groups in **Target > Capabilities**) and have downloaded them via Xcode.

Any ideas on why this could happen ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088441/the-identity-used-to-sign-the-executable-is-no-longer-valid

Comment: @sbarow I've already seen that one but nothing there helped me ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally managed to make it work though I'm not exactly sure which of the following had to be done.

1. I deleted my Apple ID and all the provisioning profiles.
2. Then I added the same Apple ID and downloaded the provisioning profiles (`Xcode > Preferences... > Accounts`)

From what I had read on SO it should have worked here, but in my case it wasn't.

So what I did was:

- going to `Window > Devices`
- then right click on my device on the left hand corner
- and click on `Show provisioning profiles...`
- I then deleted all the provisioning profiles I had on my phone

After doing what I said above it worked.

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: 'Product -> Clean' is needed.

Comment: Thanks, the last part worked for me including the product -> 'Clean'.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode: Preferences...

1. Accounts
2. Select your apple account
3. Remove that account (-)
4. Add again your apple account (+)
5. Restart Xcode
6. Run yor app!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for this error message is your team not being set. Whenever I start a project, mine defaults to none and this error message always gets me. Once I change the team to one with a valid cert, everything works

[image]